# gparted, df and resizing a hard drive partition

Tags: disk-usage, gparted

I block copied a 50 GB linux partition (almost full, 92% used), from
 a disk which had started to have some errors to a 666 GB partition
 of a 750 new hard drive using   ddrescue -v -d -r 3 -f /dev/... /dev/...
 After using grub I was able to boot from the new hard drive 
 without any noticeable problems.

While I somehow expected that I might need to resize the
 result of my copying, now both gparted and df report that my new drive
 is close to being full, however in different ways: gparted says that 660 GB 
 have been used out of 666 GB available in the partition, and  df claims the partition has 41 GB in use out of a total of 47 GB.

I don't understand what is wrong, nor how to interpret
 the vastly different sizes of /dev/sda1/
by gparted and df. I am lost and would appreciate suggestions
 about how one can recover the use of the space in the new disk 
 which I expected to be more than 90% free, even after putting the
 contents of the old.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to resize the filesystem after resizing the partition using `resize2fs`.

From the [resize2fs man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs)

The `resize2fs` program will resize ext2, ext3, or ext4 file systems. It can be used to enlarge or shrink an unmounted file system located on device. If the filesystem is mounted, it can be used to expand the size of the mounted filesystem, assuming the kernel supports on-line resizing.

The command to resize the filesystem you inquired about is:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Please improve your answer with further explanation on why this solves the problem.

Comment: @benjamin-connelly: Am I correct in reading your suggestion as that I need to do **two things:** **1)** resize the partition (using gparted? The resize2fs man page says that resize2fs does not manipulate the size of partitions); and then **2)** resize the filesystem using sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1 (without any arguments?). -- At first I thought that you had suggested to do both using resize2fs, but at the moment of action I hesitated. Many thanks for your reply and sorry about the time it took me to reply.